# Does application exception roll the transaction back?

Tags: jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I have a stateless bean class TestBean:

```
package samples;

import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Stateless
public class TestBean {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doIt() throws Exception {
        em.createQuery("UPDATE Employee e SET e.salary = e.salary * 1.05").executeUpdate();
        throw new Exception("Let us stop it!");
    }
}
```

Does the EntityManager commit the transaction and the update would take place?

Comment: What happens when you try it? We can't really tell you definitively yes or no because we don't know what you're full environment is. In theory, yes, the transaction _should_ get rolled back. Why don't you try it and let us know.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear That is a pure JPA question, rather then its implementations like Hibernate.

Answer (score 4):

By default EJB bean should rollback the transaction only on system exceptions, that is: RuntimeException, RemoteException. This kind of exceptions are wrapped-up in EJBException.

If you throw application exception (**as it is in your example**), EJB bean won't rollback the transaction- it expects you to handle the exception. Application exceptions are those that do not extend RuntimeException or RemoteException.

You can make your EJB bean to rollback on appication exceptions by annotating it with:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
```

Comment: That means that methods with REQUIRES_NEW should not throw catched (application) exceptions.

Comment: REQUIRES_NEW has nothing to do with exception handling in EJB. It specifies EJB bean to run business method with new transaction (for example when you invoke one business method from another one- by default, they share same transaction).

Comment: `REQUIRES_NEW` does always start a new transaction (suspending the transaction of the caller before it starts a new one and resumes it when it is finished). If you want to mark the transaction for rollback when an application exception occurs in your method, call the `setRollbackOnly()` method from your catch-block. Then the container rolls back the transaction as soon as the method finishes